# Radeon graphics card gone

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a HP ProBook 470 with integrated Intel and AMD Radeon graphics. I am trying to install the right drivers now to switch to the Radeon and for that I switched a setting in my BIOS (Enable hybrid graphics). But, now the AMD Radeon doesn't show up anymore in the Device Manager (I am using Windows 10), even after setting the switch in the BIOS back.

What can I do to enable the AMD Radeon and then switch to it, so I can actually use the hardware that I have?

Comment: Enter BIOS again to verify the change was saved. Then power down, unplug the unit and remove the battery. After that, hold down the power button for 30 seconds. Reconnect and restart to see if it is recognized.

Comment: You need to install the AMD drivers from HP... if there are no Windows 10 drivers for the AMD graphics, use the AMD reference drivers. This should return the switchable menus and allow changing of the GPU based on application and power source again. Both Intel and AMD graphics drivers must be installed simultaneously. And it is normal not to "see" them in device manager prior to installation.

Comment: @CharlieRB I checked the BIOS setting (it was set), and after a reboot after night, it appeared again. Weird ...